# pg_dump not found in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I installed postgres, however when I try dump my database schema (sql) in a rails project I keep getting this error message in the console **pg_dump not found in rails**. Can anyone help with how to resolve this issue?

Comment: When acting as the same user running the rails command, does `which pg_dump` in your shell resolve an executable named pg_dump?

Comment: Any result with this? Can you post an answer or close/delete the question?

Answer (score 2):

You can figure things out this way:

```
find / -name pg_dump
dirname ${OUTPUT_FROM_ABOVE_COMMAND}

PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/dir/from/above/dirname/call; export PATH
```

And you should be good to go.