# Command 'pg_dump' not found in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-dump

I am using pg_dump to transfer databases on a rail app between my local drive and my server (heroku). I get the following error message

```
Command 'pg_dump' not found
```

Which I do not manage to resolve

I have looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263299/pg-dump-not-found-in-rails).

I have also tried to re-install postgresql as requested by the console

```
sudo apt install postgresql-client-common
```

I am using the following version of postgresql

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.5 (Ubuntu 10.5-1.pgdg16.04+1)
```

When I run

```
sudo dpkg -l|grep postgresql-client
```

I get a 4 lines ouputs

```
ii postgresql-client 10+192.pgd16.04+1 all front-end programes for PostgreSQL (supported version)
ii postgresql-client-10 10.5-1.pgd16.04+1 amd64 front-end programes for PostgreSQL 10
ii postgresql-client-9.5 9.5.14-1.pgd16.04+1 amd64 front-end programes for PostgreSQL 9.5
ii postgresql-client-common 192.pgd16.04+1 all manager for multiple PostgrSQL client versions
```

I am running out of options. Could anyone give me some tips to have the command work?

Comment: ```pg_dump``` is a utility for backing up a PostgreSQL database. It should not be in Rails. You can run it from console, the same as ```psql```

Comment: ```postgresql-client-common``` is a manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions. To install pg_dump utility you need to install ```postgresql-client``` package

Comment: Could you add to problem description output of the command ```sudo dpkg -l|grep postgresql-client```?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362443/bash-pg-dump-command-not-found